# How to prevent a variable from being created for a non-physical property in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, properties

In modern versions of Xcode, variables are automatically created to back properties. For example, `@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isOpen` would automatically create `BOOL _isOpen`. Is there a way to prevent such variables from being created when the property is meant to be non-physical? In the following example of a non-physical `isOpen` property, `_isOpen` is not needed. It is actually detrimental, because I've had co-workers inadvertdently use `_isOpen` and wonder why nothing would happen.

```
- (void) setIsOpen:(BOOL)isOpen
{
    if (isOpen) {
        [self.specialView open]
    } else {
        [self.specialView close];
    }
}

- (BOOL) isOpen
{
    return self.specialView.alpha > 0.0;
}
```

Comment: if you override both getter and setter and don't have `@synthesize`, no ivar will be created

Comment: If you specify `@dynamic isOpen;` the ivar will not be created.

Comment: `@dynamic isOpen` is not necessary; the instance variable will not be created if both a getter and setter exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you implement both the setter & the getter the variable will not be created. From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html):

> The compiler will automatically synthesize an instance variable in all situations where it’s also synthesizing at least one accessor method. If you implement both a getter and a setter for a `readwrite` property, or a getter for a `readonly` property, the compiler will assume that you are taking control over the property implementation and won’t synthesize an instance variable automatically.

Your co-workers should not be able to reference `_isOpen` at all. I've checked your code in Xcode 4.6.3 and it behaves as per spec - no variable is created.

Comment: what happens if you implement the methods and still do `@synthesize`? Also for a more complete answer could you add the convention for implementing getters and setters?

Comment: Note that with the modern compiler, you don't need to specify `@synthesize` or `@dynamic`. (There are some tricky cases you might have to. This isn't one of them.)

Comment: @BradAllred - The OP isn't using an `@synthesize` as there is no need with recent compilers. *If* you choose to and just include `@synthesize property` then you *will* get a synthesised variable, named *without* the underscore as you are now using the old-style rather than the modern synthesis. For this and other esoteric combinations see the docs. The question includes the setter/getter pattern, again for more details see the docs.

Comment: @CRD I actually know all that, I was suggesting you edit your answer for completeness...

Comment: @BradAllred - Yeah, I know some of my answers are long and detailed, with plenty of background etc., in an attempt to help the reader gain an understanding, or bore them ;-) But sometimes you just answer the question in the context, and if folk want to explore further there is always the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify both the getter and the setter. Assuming you do that, no instance variable is created.

Note that you can specify a different name for the getter, too. For boolean properties, the `is` prefix is usually dropped, though in the case of "open" I might leave it. I think it's clearer with the prefix.

For other boolean properties, though, something like this might be preferred:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isOpen) BOOL open;
```

Then:

- implement `setOpen` and `isOpen`.
- read using `BOOL value = object.open` or `BOOL value = [object isOpen]`
- write using `object.open = value` or `[object setOpen:value]`.

Using `@dynamic` is not necessary; the recent compiler will detect you've specified both the getter and setter. `@synthesize` should not be necessary either. (There are a few edge cases; if you run into a case where it is necessary, by all means use it there).

Note, however, that I'm talking about the **modern runtime** here. 32-bit OSX targets use the legacy runtime, which has different rules.